# Remove navigator toolbar from top on index page only

Tags: onsen-ui

How can i remove navigator toolbar from top on single page index.html, but i want ons.navigator.pushPage functionality for some button on index.html is it possible?

It can be achieved by hide-toolbar="true" on index page and get back false on page1 , but after move to page1, i am not able to view left button on top header, and ons.navigator.popPage() is also not working on my button.

Answer (score 2):

You can vanish navigation bar by

## index.html

```
<ons-navigator page="foo.html" hide-toolbar=true></ons-navigator>
```

http://onsenui.io/guide/components.html#navigator

And in order to display ons-navigator html on next.html, write this in foo,html

## foo.html

```
<div class="topcoat-navigation-bar">
  <div class="topcoat-navigation-bar__item center full">
    <h1 class="topcoat-navigation-bar__title">Navigation Bar</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="topcoat-navigation-bar topcoat-navigation-bar--bottom">
  <div class="topcoat-navigation-bar__line-height" style="text-align:center">Bottom Toolbar</div>
</div>
```

http://onsenui.io/themes/#navigation-bar